# How do I Digivolve?

Tags: digimon-rearise

I have an Agumon (アグモン); a Rookie (成長期 Seichouki, lit. "Child") level Digimon that is capped at Level 10, received from a gatcha roll. Ignoring the obvious lack of evolution essence, is there any way to increase the level cap to Level 20, of which is a requirement to Digivolve (進化 Shinka, lit. "Evolution") into Champion (成熟期 Seijukuki, lit. "Adult")?

[image: "進化" is grayed out even though he's 10/10]

What are requirements required to evolve, and are there any story mission I need to complete up to, or is it impossible to get a higher evolution other than to get lucky in the gatcha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use training to give your Digimon the weights etc to boost the level cap. Once you’ve trained all 6 you can upgrade to the next rank.